# Git diff - how to quit the diff listing

Tags: git

How do you quit git diff listing?

There is an `<END>` marker at the bottom of the screen, and everything I do which appears to quit the diff listing, then shows an `<END>` marker at the bottom of the screen again.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The default pager for git is `less`. To quit `less`, hit <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: add a colon infront if you get problems ":q"

Comment: Add a line to .bashrc  export LESS="$LESS -FRXK" which will allow ctrl-c to quit from less. (I only use less for git)

Comment: **vim** flashbacks